# CRITICAL:yum.main

Tags: centos, filesystems, sudo, yum, root

I went to run `sudo yum update` I get

```
error: db5 error(11) from dbenv->open: Resources temporarily unavailable
error: cannot open Packages index using db5 - Resources temporarily unavailable (11)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:
```

So then a skilled colleague pointed [this](https://www.basezap.com/error-rpmdb-open-failed-on-running-yum-update/) out to me:

> ```
> Log in to the machine using root account where you are facing the issue.
> Stash all the headers files on which yum uses for dependency resolution
> yum clean headers
> Clean yum packages cache
> yum clean packages
> Clean metadata
> yum clean metadata
> Clean dbcache
> yum clean dbcache
> Clean remaining things
> yum clean all
> Remove clean all RPM database files
> rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db.*
> Rebuilt RPM Database
> rpm -vv –rebuilddb
> Now run the update command
> yum update
> ```
>
> With this rpmdb open failed error will be fixed.

When I run `yum clean headers` I get the same error above.
What I did that may have caused this problem is I moved `/var` to a new lvm on a new pci-ssd `nvmeVg`. I have noticed two database connection errors as well.

```
/var/lib/rpm
```

> contains Basenames Conflictname
> __db.001 Dirnames Group Installtid Name Obsoletename Packages Providename Requirename Sha1header Sigmd5 Triggername

Comment: My first check would be `/var/lib/rpm`. Does it exist, and what, if anything, does it contain. I doubt that any database connection errors are related, since the RPM database is not based on a server process. What connection errors did you notice though?

Comment: updated post. The database errors are a separate issue.  Will deal with this current issue.

Comment: Move aside the __db.001 and run `rpmdb —rebuilddb` and try again?

Comment: The "resource temporarily unavailable" error indicates that the RPM database is locked. I think the lock is implemented with `/var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock`. While copying the database over to the new filesystem, you somehow kept the lock intact, or another rpm process is still up and running. First, check if there is another rpm process and kill it (if you think that's safe). If not, it **should** be safe to remove that file. However, I am not sure what is the best way to address this, and would look for inspiration on the internet.

Comment: I "mv __db.001" to /tmpRpm directory ran "rpmdb -rebuilddb" and got "rpmd: only one major mode may be speficied"

Comment: Sorry, for some reason the input turned a double dash (—) into an M-dash (–).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with rebuilding was a GNU style option so I added two dashed and it worked.  `rpmdb --rebuilddb`

Originally `/var` was 50G. When I moved `/var` to nvmeVg I increased the size with

```
lvextend -L+25G /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var
```

then tried

```
rpmdb --rebuild
```

then got

```
error: failed to create directory /var/lib/rpmrebuilddb.21957: No space left on device
```

Odd...Something process (could be my proprietary software) must be creating a log or something taking up space so I increase another +25G and boom right away `/var` is 100% full. So surely some log process I am thinking must be taking up all the space.

Comment: I notice "lsblk" /var is 125G at block level. but "df -t" /var is 50G because its a partition file system.  I have to put a bigger block device same size partition

So I "resizefs /dev/nvmeVg/var/" which removed the disk space issue and successfully rebuilt using "rpmdb --rebuilddb"  Woot

Comment: Sorted my problem, but for RHEL7 I had to use a slightly different argument `rpmdb --rebuilddb`.